# Android - GET Request using Https failing - not sure why

Tags: java, android, https, httpurlconnection, ioexception

Good Afternoon,

I have been making Http GET and POST requests to various websites using Android's HttpURLConnection object for a few weeks and have had no problems in doing so until now.

I recently have been required to make a GET request to a server using Https rather than Http.

I presumed that all I needed to do was change the object in use to a HttpsURLConnection object instead in order to access the page.

I can verify that I am able to access the page from both my desktop and mobile browsers.
The output of the page is simply text - a list of items in plain text format (generated with php on the server).

But when I try and download the information using my Android app I get an IO Exception error at the point specified below (see code block below).

The code snippet below is run in a different thread. It manages to connect and set the connection parameters, but upon trying to open the input stream it fails.

Unfortunately the error message doesn't mean a lot to me. It simply contains the url of the website with no other information.

My thoughts are that either:

a) I'm missing something when connecting using Https - any tips here would be great.
b) The website is doing something different than all the other Http based websites I've connected to in the past - which is not unlikely because of the nature of this particular website. Any suggestions here as to what some possibilities that could be stopping a GET request from getting through.

Yet to be tried: I'm planning on trying to connect with a GET request from an alternative location using a few different techniques just to make sure it's not something I'm doing in my Java code.

Hope that is clear.

Thanks,
Matt

```
 @Override
    public void run() 
    {
    String response = null;
    URL url;
    try
    {
        url = new URL(urlstr);
        HttpsURLConnection con;
        try
        {
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try 
            {
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                con.setReadTimeout(10000);
                con.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
                //this is where we fall over - after this line....it raises an IOException - see below for details.
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                while(true)
                {
                    int ch = in.read();
                    if(ch==-1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    response = response + Character.toString((char) ch);
                }
                in.close();
            } 
            catch (ProtocolException e) 
            {
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            //IO Exception is raised.  The error message (e.getMessage()) is simply the url string...not very helpful.
        }
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e1)
    {
    }
    if(response!=null)
    {
        //do stuff with response...
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace: (I can verify that the file does indeed exist however!)

```
04-24 15:16:22.854: W/System.err(12830): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://         (IVE REMOVED THE WEBSITE FOR PRIVACY PURPOSES FOR NOW)
04-24 15:16:22.854: W/System.err(12830):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
04-24 15:16:22.854: W/System.err(12830):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
04-24 15:16:22.854: W/System.err(12830):    at com.lloydm.app.MainActivity$MainListing.run(MainActivity.java:1733)
04-24 15:16:22.854: W/System.err(12830):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

(stack trace reformatted)

Comment: The error message might mean more to people who can help with your problem than it does to you.  Can you provide a complete stack trace?

Comment: Edit - removed this edit - reproduced in main body of text - was stack trace.

Comment: File is not on the server. Check your url.

Comment: I can type the url in manually and it appears no problems. I can run an XMLHttpRequest from Javascript and it is there - though I get a cross origin domain problem despite having the right header information in the php code....so it is not that the file is not on the server.

Comment: Have a look at my [gist](https://gist.github.com/hgoebl/11244369). You could try it with your URL and see what the output is. Your exception handling and the way to get information about the error is not optimal, so with your code we can't help you. BTW concatenating a String in this way should not be done -> use StringBuilder!

Comment: Okay..it's been a while both myself and my systems admin have been trying to fix this.  It's nothing in the android code - I get the same error in javascript from a remotely hosted webpage.  It seems to be cross origin resource sharing that is the problem.  However I have put all the appropriate headers into the php file and still it rejects it saying (in javascript) that it's a CORS problem.  A bit stumped.

Comment: Okay it turned out to be something on our hosted server's end. They had a setting that needed to be changed. Our IT guy for the network spoke to our ISP and they must have changed something and now it works.